# Howto pass parameter to ajax callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function f(id) {
    $.ajax("http://example.com/example",{
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $("#"+id).text(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Success callback function can reach and read `id` variable just fine, but since ajax calls are non-blocking, won't `id` change with another function `f()` call, happening after starting ajax request but before getting response? How can I save and pass the `id` at the time of requesting ajax call?

Comment: This is called a closure. The success callback is a closure which has access to the outer scope. If f() is called multiple times, each will still access its 'version' of the id variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> won't id change with another function f() call

No, because every time a function is called, a copy of the variable passed as a parameter is created.

Consider the following situation:

```js
let a = 1;

function change(param) {
   param = 2;
   console.log(param);
}

change(a);

console.log(a);
```

This code will print `2` and then `1` because `param` is a copy of `a` and therefore changing it doesn't affect `a`.

Things become a little more complicated when passing a reference to an object:

```js
let a = {field: 1};

function change(param) {
    param.field = 2; // changes the original object field
    param = {field: 7}; // changes the value of param variable
    console.log(param.field);
}

change(a);

console.log(a.field);
```

The console will print `7` and then `2`. In this case `a` is a reference, not a primitive value. And although `param` is a copy of `a`, it is a copy of the reference, and this copy refers to the *same* object.

So `param.field = 2` changes the `field` of the original object. That's why we get `2` in the second output.

But if we assign a new value to `param`, we overwrite the reference to `a` with a reference to the new object `{field: 7}`. And since `param` is a copy of `a`, original object is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't change. It will start an entire new `ajax` request with it own success callback. Which will, most likely, resolve sometime after the first one updating it again. This is true even if you called `f()` again BEFORE the server returns a response to you. Your scope will be preserved.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop